# breaking a mathematical range in equal parts

Tags: java

I have a mathematical range [a, b] and I am trying to break the range into 'n' equal parts.
The numbers, a and b can be anything but for an example let's assume the range is [0, 1].

Basically what I am trying to do is let's say that if `n = 4` and the range is `[0, 1]` then I want breakpoints for that range to be calculated as `[.25, .5, .75]` because these divide `[0, 1]` into 4 equal points. Similarly, if the range is `[0, 1]` and `n = 2`, I want the breakpoints to be [.5].

What is the fastest way of computing these breakpoints in java? Is there a built-in function for doing this sort of thing?

Comment: Not likely that there's anything built-in like that in Java.  Further, you don't specify if you're using an ADT or arrays to solve the problem.  Also, "speed" is ever so slightly secondary to actually getting a working solution, so when you're implementing this, don't worry about performance yet.

Comment: If you get some code working, you can post it and ask whether the speed can be improved.  But a question like that probably belongs on Code Review instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks... I already have code to do this... I was just curious if there is a faster way of doing this using some built-in function since matlab has one. So I was just curious if Java had something similar or not. Thanks though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say you have numbers `[x,y]` and you want `n` parts.  Then you could do calculate that difference:

```
diff = (y-x)/n
```

Now create a variable `d` which equals to `x` and loop from `1` to `n`.  As you loop, add `diff` to `d` and print `d`.  Some pseudo code:

```
diff = (y-x)/n;     
d = x;
for(1 to n)
    d = d + diff
    print(d)
```

**NOTE**:  Use `double`.

Comment: d should be initialised to x not 0

Answer (score 2):

If the range is `[a,b]` and it has to be divided in `n` partitions, then one approach can be:-

```
public class Range
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double lowLimit = a;
        double highLimit = b;
        double difference = (b-a);
        double partition = difference/n;   // n is the number partitions of the range [a,b]
        System.out.println("The partitions are:");
        for(int i = 1;i<=n; i++)
            {
                    lowLimit += partition;
                    System.out.print(lowLimit+"\t");
            }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the double from the loop because in Java, work with floating point should be avoided because it might lead some really weird results.

Comment: What if lowLimit can be negative?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need (to print breaks, or System break on those breakPoints), anyway, both are over here

```
double division += (maxRange - minRange)/n;
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
    double minRange = 0;
    double maxRange = 1;
    double breaks[i] = division;
    //System.out.println(breaks[i]); ----------------------USE THIS ONE IF PRINTING BREAKPOINT IS NEEDED
    //new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); --------THIS LINE STOPS THE PROGRAM UNTIL YOU PRESS A KEY
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code just to give you an idea where to start:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int n = 4;

double fraction = (b - a) / (double) n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    System.out.println("Lower bound: " + i * fraction + "; Upper bound: " + (i + 1) * fraction);
}
```

Comment: This program prints all 0. Doesn't run properly.

Answer (score 0):

`double dx = ((upper_bound - lower_bound)/n)`

This will calculate the space between each point in the range.

If you wanted to place these points in an array, you would do as follows:

```
double value = lower_bound; 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    double value += dx;
    double_array[i] = value;
}
```

You haven't specified what sort of data structure you are working with, so beyond this simple array implementation I cannot help you without further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with while loop:

```
public class Breakpoint
{
  public Breakpoint()
  {
    double start = 0;
    double end = 1;

    double n = 4;

    double difference = (end - start) / n;
    double value = start;

    while (value < end)
    {
      value += difference;
      System.out.println(value);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new Breakpoint();
  }
}
```